# Not able to take screenshot of alert box in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium i want to take the screenshot of alert box whenever the alert is popped.
The code i have written is as below:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import time


class SearchXSS(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def test_search_in_python_org(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://testfire.net/")
    ele = driver.find_element_by_name("txtSearch")
    ele.send_keys("<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>")
    ele.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')
        alert.accept()
    except NoAlertPresentException as e:
        print "no alert to accept "
    fo.close()


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I am facing the issue while taking the screenshot.The Error message is as below

> ====================================================================== ERROR: test_search_in_python_org (**main**.SearchXSS)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/programs/sele/testx.py", line 22, in
>   test_search_in_python_org
>       driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 798, in get_screenshot_as_file
>       png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 817, in get_screenshot_as_png
>       return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 827, in get_screenshot_as_base64
>       return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 191, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text')) UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert
>   Text: amSessionId=92632533494 Message: Unexpected modal dialog (text:
>   amSessionId=92632533494) Stacktrace:
>       at fxdriver.modals.closeUnhandledAlert/< (file:///tmp/tmpdnEJbt/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/prompt-service.js:4745)
>       at  (http://testfire.net/search.aspx?txtSearch=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28document.cookie%29%3C%2Fscript%3E:80)
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 10.346s
>
> FAILED (errors=1) [Finished in 10.4s with exit code 1]

Help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not take `screenshot` with the `alert` box, you need to handle `alert` first means `accept` or `dismiss` then go to take screenshot because when selenium goes to take screenshot with alert present, it always throws the `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` as you are getting, **It is not possible to take screenshot with the `alert` box using `selenium`**. So you need to do as below :-

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')
```

If you want to take screenshot with `alert`, you should try some different approach with some other library, In java there is `Robot` class present which be able to take `screenshot` in such type of scenario but I'm not sure what is the equivalent in python for this.

Comment: Thank you Saurabh but i want to take screenshot of `alert` box that is the intention..

Comment: @user3513995 see if any other library provided in python to take screenshots instead..in Java there is a `Robot` class to take screenshots in this situation may be something available equivalent to this in python...:)